# Unable to get the custom extension build_runner dart

Tags: flutter, dart, build-runner

I am trying to get the `example_model.fti.dart` file
However, I get only `example_model.fti.g.part` at the output

I've tried different variations of build_extensions

```
    .fti.g.part
    .fti.g.dart
    .fti.part
    .fti.dart
    ...
```

with my `build.yaml`

```yaml
builders:
  generators:
    target: ":generators"
    import: "package:generators/generators.dart"
    builder_factories: ["fti"]
    build_extensions: { ".dart": [".fti.dart"] }
    auto_apply: dependents
    build_to: source
    applies_builders: ["source_gen|combining_builder"]
#    runs_before:
#      - source_gen|combining_builder
```

My worst result is `example_model.fti.g.part`, and best `example_model.g.dart`
but `example_model.g.dart` conflicting with json_serializable
How I can get `example_model.fti.dart`